# Is it possible to use markup in frontmatter or config texts (themeConfig) in VuePress?

Tags: markdown, vuepress, markdown-it

Some texts in VuePress are taken from the page's frontmatter or some config, e.g. `.vuepress/config.js`. Especially in the themeConfig (of the default theme) you can specify e.g. the locale's `selectText`. I would like to use an image there (the flags of the languages).

However, it seems that there no markup is supported: HTML is escaped and markdown is not converted.

I tried to use the emoji flags for the languages, but these doesn't look nice in all browsers.

```js
// .vuepress/config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  themeConfig: {
    locales: {
      "/": {
        selectText: " / ",
     //...
```

So, is there a way how I could use some sort of markup in these places?

Is there some hook where I could inject some render function to adapt these texts?

(Or do I need to file a feature request? ;-))